# Define own directory name for Magento composer extension

Tags: composer, modman

My Magento environment is structured as following:

- `composer.json` which includes `"aoepeople/composer-installers": "*"` and a list of Magento modules that deploy the code into my `.modman` directory.  From here, i deploy the files through `modman deploy-all` into the Magento root folder.

So these are my steps, when a new extension update is available:

- composer update
- Inspect changes of the module code in the .modman folder
- git commit
- modman deploy-all
- git push: Starts remote Magento deployment

This works as expected.

When i use the package `avstudnitz/scopehints` or `mb/translate` in my `composer.json`, the folders `.modman/scopehints` and `.modman/translate` are created. However, i would prefer a foldername including the vendor name, like the name of the Magento module itself, such as `.modman/AvS_ScopeHint` and `.modman/MB_Translate` for clarity.

Is there a way to define the composer deploy foldername for each Magento package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. In the `extras.installer-paths` configuration, you can use the variables `{$name}` and `{$vendor}`. But there is no way to get the name of the Magento module itself because it is not part of the module's composer configuration.

I use configuration like this:

```
  "extra":{
    "installer-paths": {
      "www/" : [ "type:magento-source" ],
      ".modman/{$vendor}_{$name}/" : [ "type:magento-module" ]
    }
  },
```

which results in paths such as `.modman/avstudnitz_scopehint` (coming from the composer package name `avstudnitz/scopehint`

Comment: @fschmegler: Is there a way to capitalize the first letter of the $vendor and $name variable?

Comment: Not without modification of the composer installer (you could fork it and add `ucfirst()` at the right place). But it's still not guaranteed that the result is exactly the Magento module name, so it might be misleading